# Fastest possible byte array concatenation method

Tags: java, performance, arrays, concatenation

I got a map containing n parts of a message as a byte array. After the last piece has found his way into the map, the message has to be concatenated. I found two solutions which should meet the requirements. First one is using System.arraycopy:

```
public byte[] getMessageBytes() throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    for (final Map.Entry<Short,byte[]> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        byte[] entryBytes = entry.getValue();
        byte[] temp = new byte[bytes.length + entryBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, temp, 0, bytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(entryBytes, 0, temp, bytes.length, entryBytes.length);
        bytes = temp;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

And second one is using ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
public byte[] getMessageBytes() throws IOException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (final Map.Entry<Short,byte[]> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        baos.write(entry.getValue());
    }
    baos.flush();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

What is the better method seen from the angle of performance and memory usage?
Is there an alternative way of doing the concatenation which is even better?

Comment: Have you benchmarked these and found them not fast enough?

Comment: is this really your bottleneck?

Comment: @Poindexter I found this takes some time within the hole process if the map has lots of entries. So I looked for an improvement.

Comment: Can you just remove the use of the map and concatenate from the start?

Comment: Often its better to do these things as you go. Can you create a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of a Map from the start. BTW a Short and an Integer uses the same amount of memory.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I allready had this solution, but accessing an ByteArrayOutputStream from multiple threads is synchronized and slow.

Comment: @user1291492 the count of entries can be very high. If I can do this faster it would improve the process.

Comment: @Aidos Using the map gives me the advantage of inserting the values parallel from multiple threads, otherwise I hade to synchronize it.

Comment: If you know the size in advance you can make the reads concurrent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you can find out the size of the message by adding up the lengths of the pieces, I would:

1. add up the lengths of the pieces, and allocate the output array;
2. use a loop to `arraycopy()` each piece into the correct position in the output array.

This is likely to be memory-efficient and fast. However, only profiling can tell the full story.

Answer (score 4):

This should perform even better than your first version (not tested)

```
public byte[] getMessageBytes() throws IOException {
    long amount = 0L;
    long offset = 0L;
    // no reason to use entrySet() if you just use the values
    for (byte[] arr : myMap.values()) {
        amount += arr.length;
    }
    byte[] dest = new byte[amount];
    for (byte[] arr : myMap.values()) {
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, dest, offset, arr.length);
        offset += arr.length;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

(This answer is roughly equivalent to aix's)

Comment: Does this assume that the order you wish to concatenate the arrays is the order of the values set? It's been a while since I've written java, but I don't think there is an order gaurantee for the values() Set is there?

Comment: @Aidos true, but since the OP used that, so did I. and while the order is not guaranteed (unless it's a SortedMap), all map implementations I know of will iterate in the same order when called multiple times unless the map has changed

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to test and compare for your particular situation.

Is that a SortedMap, like a TreeMap or are you actually merging the bytes randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution that creates a new array for each iteration is O(n^2), which is a problem if you have many entries. Plus it is fairly complex.

Using ByteArrayOutputStream is better for two reasons: it runs in O(n), and it is very simple.

Most likely a little bit faster is: if you first calculate the total size, and then use System.arraycopy. But I would only do that if the ByteArrayOutputStream is *really* too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the size first and allocating the result once should be the fastest solution to return a byte array.

If you use the resulting byte array as an `InputStream` later on, and depending on the combined size of the arrays, the fastest way might be to not concatenate at all. In that case you could create a [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/SequenceInputStream.html) wrapping several `ByteArrayInputStreams`. Untested sample code:

```
Collection<byte[]> values = map.values();
List<ByteArrayInputStream> streams = new ArrayList<ByteArrayInputStream>(values.size());
for (byte[] bytes : values) {
    streams.add(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
}
return new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the NATIVE CODE.**

```
    /*
     * public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest,
     *      int destPos, int length)
     *
     * The description of this function is long, and describes a multitude
     * of checks and exceptions.
     */
    static void Dalvik_java_lang_System_arraycopy(const u4* args, JValue* pResult)
    {
        ArrayObject* srcArray = (ArrayObject*) args[0];
        int srcPos = args[1];
        ArrayObject* dstArray = (ArrayObject*) args[2];
        int dstPos = args[3];
        int length = args[4];
        /* Check for null pointers. */
        if (srcArray == NULL) {
            dvmThrowNullPointerException("src == null");
            RETURN_VOID();
        }
        if (dstArray == NULL) {
            dvmThrowNullPointerException("dst == null");
            RETURN_VOID();
        }
        /* Make sure source and destination are arrays. */
        if (!dvmIsArray(srcArray)) {
            dvmThrowArrayStoreExceptionNotArray(((Object*)srcArray)->clazz, "source");
            RETURN_VOID();
        }
        if (!dvmIsArray(dstArray)) {
            dvmThrowArrayStoreExceptionNotArray(((Object*)dstArray)->clazz, "destination");
            RETURN_VOID();
        }
        /* avoid int overflow */
        if (srcPos < 0 || dstPos < 0 || length < 0 ||
            srcPos > (int) srcArray->length - length ||
            dstPos > (int) dstArray->length - length)
        {
            dvmThrowExceptionFmt(gDvm.exArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,
                "src.length=%d srcPos=%d dst.length=%d dstPos=%d length=%d",
                srcArray->length, srcPos, dstArray->length, dstPos, length);
            RETURN_VOID();
        }
        ClassObject* srcClass = srcArray->clazz;
        ClassObject* dstClass = dstArray->clazz;
        char srcType = srcClass->descriptor[1];
        char dstType = dstClass->descriptor[1];
        /*
         * If one of the arrays holds a primitive type, the other array must
         * hold the same type.
         */
        bool srcPrim = (srcType != '[' && srcType != 'L');
        bool dstPrim = (dstType != '[' && dstType != 'L');
        if (srcPrim || dstPrim) {
            if (srcPrim != dstPrim || srcType != dstType) {
                dvmThrowArrayStoreExceptionIncompatibleArrays(srcClass, dstClass);
                RETURN_VOID();
            }
            if (false) ALOGD("arraycopy prim[%c] dst=%p %d src=%p %d len=%d",
                srcType, dstArray->contents, dstPos,
                srcArray->contents, srcPos, length);
            switch (srcType) {
            case 'B':
            case 'Z':
                /* 1 byte per element */
                memmove((u1*) dstArray->contents + dstPos,
                    (const u1*) srcArray->contents + srcPos,
                    length);
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'S':
                /* 2 bytes per element */
                move16((u1*) dstArray->contents + dstPos * 2,
                    (const u1*) srcArray->contents + srcPos * 2,
                    length * 2);
                break;
            case 'F':
            case 'I':
                /* 4 bytes per element */
                move32((u1*) dstArray->contents + dstPos * 4,
                    (const u1*) srcArray->contents + srcPos * 4,
                    length * 4);
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'J':
                /*
                 * 8 bytes per element.  We don't need to guarantee atomicity
                 * of the entire 64-bit word, so we can use the 32-bit copier.
                 */
                move32((u1*) dstArray->contents + dstPos * 8,
                    (const u1*) srcArray->contents + srcPos * 8,
                    length * 8);
                break;
            default:        /* illegal array type */
                ALOGE("Weird array type '%s'", srcClass->descriptor);
                dvmAbort();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * Neither class is primitive.  See if elements in "src" are instances
             * of elements in "dst" (e.g. copy String to String or String to
             * Object).
             */
            const int width = sizeof(Object*);
            if (srcClass->arrayDim == dstClass->arrayDim &&
                dvmInstanceof(srcClass, dstClass))
            {
                /*
                 * "dst" can hold "src"; copy the whole thing.
                 */
                if (false) ALOGD("arraycopy ref dst=%p %d src=%p %d len=%d",
                    dstArray->contents, dstPos * width,
                    srcArray->contents, srcPos * width,
                    length * width);
                move32((u1*)dstArray->contents + dstPos * width,
                    (const u1*)srcArray->contents + srcPos * width,
                    length * width);
                dvmWriteBarrierArray(dstArray, dstPos, dstPos+length);
            } else {
                /*
                 * The arrays are not fundamentally compatible.  However, we
                 * may still be able to do this if the destination object is
                 * compatible (e.g. copy Object[] to String[], but the Object
                 * being copied is actually a String).  We need to copy elements
                 * one by one until something goes wrong.
                 *
                 * Because of overlapping moves, what we really want to do
                 * is compare the types and count up how many we can move,
                 * then call move32() to shift the actual data.  If we just
                 * start from the front we could do a smear rather than a move.
                 */
                Object** srcObj;
                int copyCount;
                ClassObject*   clazz = NULL;
                srcObj = ((Object**)(void*)srcArray->contents) + srcPos;
                if (length > 0 && srcObj[0] != NULL)
                {
                    clazz = srcObj[0]->clazz;
                    if (!dvmCanPutArrayElement(clazz, dstClass))
                        clazz = NULL;
                }
                for (copyCount = 0; copyCount < length; copyCount++)
                {
                    if (srcObj[copyCount] != NULL &&
                        srcObj[copyCount]->clazz != clazz &&
                        !dvmCanPutArrayElement(srcObj[copyCount]->clazz, dstClass))
                    {
                        /* can't put this element into the array */
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (false) ALOGD("arraycopy iref dst=%p %d src=%p %d count=%d of %d",
                    dstArray->contents, dstPos * width,
                    srcArray->contents, srcPos * width,
                    copyCount, length);
                move32((u1*)dstArray->contents + dstPos * width,
                    (const u1*)srcArray->contents + srcPos * width,
                    copyCount * width);
                dvmWriteBarrierArray(dstArray, 0, copyCount);
                if (copyCount != length) {
                    dvmThrowArrayStoreExceptionIncompatibleArrayElement(srcPos + copyCount,
                            srcObj[copyCount]->clazz, dstClass);
                    RETURN_VOID();
                }
            }
        }
        RETURN_VOID();
    }
```